# draconic champion prestige class requirements are vague

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

I am a half orc, barbarian 4 fighter 1 and would like to get the draconic champion prestige class but the requirements are vague. How do you interpret them?

> **Entry Requirements**
>
> - Base Attack Bonus +3
> - Dragon friend must have regular contact with a dragon.
> - Special: Pass the trials or rituals of their sect.

[Source](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Draconic_Champion_%283.5e_Prestige_Class%29)

Comment: I got the class from http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Draconic_Champion_%283.5e_Prestige_Class%29

Comment: That looks like a homebrew class. As such there's no official rules on it, so it's going to be hard to answer your question.

Comment: It looks to be an *unfinished* homebrew class. I would just talk to your GM to see if they'll let you use the class without the special pre-reqs.

Comment: What specifically do you find vague? Maybe you could elaborate a little

Comment: Even if it were a finished class, things like "pass trials" or "have contact with a friend" are up to the DM to implement/allow.  Infact, I think there's a feat or PRC that requires a similar relationship with a fey

Comment: I simply meant that the requirements aren't clearly explained or examined on the wiki page, as far as I could see. Perhaps if they were they would be more easily implemented. Right now the best option is to simply ignore them, or have the GM invent his own context.

Comment: @Ben-Jamin You’re probably thinking of Nymph’s Kiss, which actually mentions the fey girlfriend in the *benefits* section >.>

Comment: Actually, Nymph's Kiss, despite the name, just makes a passing reference to you having an "intimate relationship" with a fey creature. That certainly could be interpreted as girlfriend/wife/friend-with-benefits, but it's also quite possible to go with a broader definition of intimate, and give that feat to a character with a close friendship to a fey. Handy if the feat would otherwise be good on a character, but the girlfriend angle doesn't fit into your character's story.

Answer (score 4):

**It's All Guesswork**
Lord Rock's only [contribution](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Special%3aContributions/Lord_Rock) to [*D&D Wiki*](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Main_Page) is the [draconic champion](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Draconic_Champion_%283.5e_Prestige_Class%29) prestige class. That makes determining the intent of his prestige class's requirements pretty much impossible.

But I'm willing to speculate. The campaign in which this prestige class would meet with DM approval is highly optimized, probably with PCs using [Tier 1 or 2](http://www.ruleofcool.com/smf/index.php/topic,640.0.html) characters like clerics, druids, psions, and wizards to the best of those characters' abilities... and one player insisted on starting as a fighter. Maybe by level 3 but more likely at level 6 with the nominal fighter PC having advanced as Bbn1/Ftr1/Clr1/Rog1/Mnk2, it was obvious to the DM and everyone else at the table that the fighter wasn't keeping up and wasn't *going* to keep up. Rather than  the DM telling the player, "Dude, just play a higher tier class!" and forcing the PC into retiring or the DM giving the fighter multiple artifacts, the DM said, "I'm going to write up a high-powered prestige class that will let you spend your Wealth by Level on things that let you do cool stuff rather than force you to spend all your cash on survival gear to scrape sadly by."

Also, it's also obvious that the class is based in the DM's campaign. In a section excised from the 3.5 *Dungeon Master's Guide* the 3.0 *Dungeon Master's Guide* offers the following advice:

> Dungeon Masters should use prestige classes as a tool for world-building as well as a reward for achieving high level. They set characters in the milieu and put them in the context of the world. (27)

But even the 3.5 *Dungeon Master's Guide* says, "The best prestige classes for your campaign are the ones you make yourself" (176). Reread the introductory flavor text; the DM who wrote that description has a campaign that pits dragon gods' servants against one another, and this is a dragon god's servant. A chosen one. Somebody special. This is a campaign-specific prestige class, and possibly a character-specific prestige class (although it wouldn't surprise me were there a rival with levels in the prestige class on the other side of fence). Perhaps not specific to the same degree as [Elothar, Warrior of Bladereach](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Elothar_Warrior_of_Bladereach_%283.5e_Prestige_Class%29), but it's specific nonetheless.

And that's my guess as to how the draconic champion prestige class came about. The class is a valid solution to that DM's problem, and it's a solution that I endorse: none of the other players would have any interest in such a class, despite its power, because they are already playing tier 1s to the hilt. The fighter player felt left out, so the DM made a class for him that was both powerful and integral to the campaign.

**Addressing the Requirements**

- **Base Attack Bonus +3.** This seems low. I think it's probably here at all because that was the PC's Base Attack Bonus at the time. Maybe the intended PC suffered from Level Adjustment, possibly as a half-dragon? Were I DM I would struggle to allow a character taking levels in this prestige class starting at character level 4, entering as a Bbn1/Ftr2.
- **Must have regular contact with a dragon.** This is a role-playing requirement, so defining *regular* and *contact*--and perhaps even *dragon*--is the DM's call. Is the venerable dragonwrought kobold PC sufficient? Maybe. Were I DM in a similar position to the DM I speculate created the class, I'd have the PC already meet this requirement *via* the campaign. Depending on the rules used, once a prestige class requirement's met and a level in it's gained, the character needn't meet the requirements any longer, so *maintaining* contact with a dragon is unnecessary. Any campaign using this class as written would probably have regular contact with dragons *anyway*, though.
- **Pass the trials or rituals of their sect.** This is another role-playing requirement. Again, these are DM-driven, but I'd make it something impossible for other PCs to achieve, maybe tests of strength (if the other PCs possess low Str scores) or resisting effects *via* Fortitude saving throws (the speculative sample PC has a *really high* base Fort save bonus)--done without magical assistance, of course.

I wouldn't expect any character to enter this class *before* non-spellcasting characters become obsolete. In a highly optimized game that's usually after level 6, and in a mid-optimized game that's usually after level 9. Your Bbn4/Ftr1 is right on track if the other PCs are all tier 1s; I'd spend the next level exploring the campaign world's dragon gods and seeing what feat I'd need to take as a Bbn4/Ftr2 (or Bbn4/Ftr1/Rgr1 or whatever) to assure passage of the "trials and rituals" when taking the 1st level in draconic champion at character level 7.

But if the other PCs *aren't* tier 1s or 2s this prestige class will be a *much* harder sell. And if the other *are* tier 3 and below PCs and *don't* already have equally high-powered options available, expect a dragon ambassador and a dragon thief to be pitched to your table shortly after you pitch this.

**Addressing the Class**
Although I think the class itself could be better written, it's obvious the *DM* understood it. The DM knew he didn't want the PC's fast healing special ability to work in combat, for instance, and might even know what the description of the fast healing ability means when it says the draconic champion's fast healing "ability continues to heal even when they are past negative 10" although I don't. (I assume it's supposed to bring the draconic champion back to life out of combat--which is kind of cool in that it actually encourages the draconic champion to leap into battle fearlessly without caring about depleting party resources were he to die.) Anyone wanting to include this class in his campaign is going to have to rewrite chunks of it even if he is running a Servants of the Dragon Gods campaign or whatever. Vital information is just missing--the links to the first, second, third, and final molts, for example, go nowhere. A lot of the class is in the DM's head and at the DM's table rather than on the page.

Further, as the [discussion](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Talk%3aDraconic_Champion_%283.5e_Prestige_Class%29) of the prestige class shows, DM's'll look at this prestige class and balk. Heck, *I* looked at this prestige class and balked at *some* of it. (I don't think an optimized fighter needs the special ability improved power attack at character level 6 to be competitive, for instance.) But I don't think it's designed to be judged, given so little context, by *us* as general readers or even us as general *players* of *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* but instead read as a method of keeping engaged a player about whom we know nothing and keeping balanced a campaign that exists only by inference solely on that page.

Comment: The links in this answer no longer take the visitor to the version of the prestige class **draconic champion** that this answer discusses; the class has since been revised (and, to be clear, was not by the class's original author). The version of the prestige class that this answer discusses can be found at the *Internet Archive* in [this link.](https://web.archive.org/web/20130624132634/https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Draconic_Champion_(3.5e_Prestige_Class))